# MVC Projects not available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to set up a new MVC 3 project.  I have Visual Studio 2008 on the box I'm using.  I can't seem to find on the ASP MVC page the answer to what VS versions it is compatible with.  However when I install MVC 3 I no longer see my old familiar MVC project links under new web project in Visual Studio.

MVC appeared to install just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

MVC 3 is only available since Visual Studio 2010.

You can use Visual Web Developer 2010 Express if you want to write MVC3 Applications
for free or buy Visual Studio 2010.

#### More Information

- [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3)
- [ASP.NET - CodePlex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks!  That wasn't listed clearly here http://www.asp.net/mvc or here http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3.